# Textures problem in LWJGL VBO`s

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, vbo

I`m working at VBO terrain renderer.
Now i have two troubles:

1. While try to render 100x100 terrain I have a 50x200 terrain
2. Textures is not rendering.

I spent really much time about it, and I have really no ideas...

How can I fix this?

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SLUh.png

My part of code:

```
public class NGINE2 {
public static int MAX_PICKING_DISTANCE = 20;
public static int RAY_RADIUS = 5;
static int w = 640;
static int h = 480;
static float oldX = 0;
static float oldY = 0;
static float oldZ = 0;

static FloatBuffer cBuffer;
static FloatBuffer vBuffer;
static FloatBuffer tBuffer;

static double[][] map;

int heightmapExaggeration = 7;
static int Size = 100;

Texture floor;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    NGINE2 ng = new NGINE2();
    ng.start();
}

void initContext() throws Exception {
    Camera.create();

    w = 800;
    h = 600;

    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(w, h));
    Display.setFullscreen(false);
    Display.create();
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    Mouse.setGrabbed(true);

    floor = TextureLoader.getTexture("JPG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("grassy.jpg"));
}

void renderLoop() {
    long time = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    cBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9 * (Size * Size * 2));
    vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9 * (Size * Size * 2));
    tBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9 * (Size * Size * 2));

    for (int x = 0; x < Size - 1; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < Size - 1; y++) {
            tBuffer.put(x * 0.25f).put((float) (map[x][y] * heightmapExaggeration)).put(y * 0.25f);
            tBuffer.put((x + 1) * 0.25f).put((float) (map[x + 1][y] * heightmapExaggeration)).put(y * 0.25f);
            tBuffer.put(x * 0.25f).put((float) (map[x][y + 1] * heightmapExaggeration)).put((y + 1) * 0.25f);
            tBuffer.put((x + 1) * 0.25f).put((float) (map[x + 1][y + 1] * heightmapExaggeration)).put((y + 1) * 0.25f);

            cBuffer.put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat());
            cBuffer.put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat());
            cBuffer.put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat());

            vBuffer.put(x * 0.25f).put((float) (map[x][y] * heightmapExaggeration)).put(y * 0.25f);
            vBuffer.put((x + 1) * 0.25f).put((float) (map[x + 1][y] * heightmapExaggeration)).put(y * 0.25f);
            vBuffer.put(x * 0.25f).put((float) (map[x][y + 1] * heightmapExaggeration)).put((y + 1) * 0.25f);

            cBuffer.put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat());
            cBuffer.put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat());
            cBuffer.put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat()).put(rand.nextFloat());

            vBuffer.put((x + 1) * 0.25f).put((float) (map[x + 1][y + 1] * heightmapExaggeration)).put((y + 1) * 0.25f);
            vBuffer.put((x + 1) * 0.25f).put((float) (map[x + 1][y] * heightmapExaggeration)).put(y * 0.25f);
            vBuffer.put(x * 0.25f).put((float) (map[x][y + 1] * heightmapExaggeration)).put((y + 1) * 0.25f);
        }
    }
    cBuffer.flip();
    vBuffer.flip();
    tBuffer.flip();
    IntBuffer ib = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(3);

    glGenBuffersARB(ib);
    int vHandle = ib.get(0);
    int cHandle = ib.get(1);
    int tHandle = ib.get(2);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, /* stride */3 << 2, 0L);

    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cHandle);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, /* stride */3 << 2, 0L);

    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, tHandle);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, tBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, /* stride */3 << 2, 0L);

    floor.bind();
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

        preRender();
        render();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60 /* desired fps */);

        // Calc FPS
        frames++;
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) >= 1000) {
            Display.setTitle(" FPS: " + (int) ((frames * 1000) / (System.currentTimeMillis() - time)));
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    floor.release();
    glDeleteBuffersARB(ib);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    ib.put(0, vHandle);
    ib.put(1, cHandle);
    Display.destroy();
}

void preRender() {

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    // GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_LINE);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, ((float) w / (float) h), 0.1f, 100.0f); // fix na błąd z kamerą

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void render() {
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

    Camera.acceptInput(0.6f);
    Camera.apply();
    // camera.vector.y = calculateHeight(camera.vector.x*4,
    // camera.vector.z*4)*heightmapExaggeration;

    for (int x = 0; x < Size * Size; x++) {
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, x * 3, 3);
    }
}

public void start() throws Exception {
    NoiseHeightMap nsh = new NoiseHeightMap(500, 24857906);
    nsh.HeightmapPNG(nsh.getHeightmap(), "C:\\Users\\Przemo\\Desktop\\mapka.png");
    map = nsh.getHeightmap();
    initContext();
    renderLoop();
}

public float calculateHeight(float x, float z) {
    float x1, x2, y1, y2, Q11, Q12, Q21, Q22;
    x1 = (int) Math.floor(x);
    x2 = (int) Math.floor(x + 1);
    y1 = (int) Math.floor(z);
    y2 = (int) Math.floor(z + 1);

    Q11 = (float) map[(int) x1][(int) y1];
    Q12 = (float) map[(int) x1][(int) y2];
    Q21 = (float) map[(int) x2][(int) y1];
    Q22 = (float) map[(int) x2][(int) y2];

    return (1f / ((x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1))) * (Q11 * (x2 - x) * (y2 - z) + Q21 * (x - x1) * (y2 - z)
            + Q12 * (x2 - x) * (z - y1) + Q22 * (x - x1) * (z - y1));
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you have OpenGL 1 in there if you use OpenGL 2 too? Why do you use ARRAY_BUFER_ARBs if those are already supported everywhere and you use OpenGL 2? Why do you use LWJGL 2?

Comment: I`m using LWJGL2 because LWJGL3 is too hard

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at some possible mistakes:

1.)

```
cBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9 * (Size * Size * 2));
vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9 * (Size * Size * 2));
tBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9 * (Size * Size * 2));
```

Why do the color and texture buffers take up the same amount of space as the vertex buffer? There should be `(size - 1)^2 * 2 * 3 * 3` spaces for the vertices (amount of squares * triangles per square * vertex per triangle * data per vertex), the same amount of color information (if you use RGB) and `(size - 1)^2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 2` texture coordinates.

2.) You only specify 4 texture coordinates for 6 vertices. Im the nested for loops you define the vertices and colors in 2 batches, one for each triangle, so you put 6 values in the vBuffer and cBuffer, but you only put 4 in the texture buffer. Textures can't render this way.

3.) You mix different versions of OpenGL. You have OpenGL 1.0 in the preRender method and a strange mix of OpenGL 1.0 and 2.0 everywhere else. You should either use OpenGL 2 only or something more modern. Don't mix 1.0 with anything.

4.) You should use shaders. The fixed function pipeline is deprecated and it's even losing support.

5.) You pass a stride of `3 << 2 = 12` for some reason. The values go from the beginning (0), just set these to 0 too.

6.) You render every triangle separately. There's no need for that. Just pass a start position of 0 and a length of `(size - 1)^2 * 2 * 3` to the drawArray function.

7.) You only draw `size^2` triangles, when there's `(size-1)^2*2` of them in total.

8.) You never dispose of the floor texture, you only unbind it

Comment: Wtf, gl1?? Where?

Comment: And texture has only 4coords, how can I define 6 verticles of texture?

Comment: @PrzemoVi Your while preRender method uses almost purely gl1. You need to define the texture coord for each vertex, there are 6 vertices -> you need to define 6 texture coords for each square. Please try looking up a tutorial about LWJGL., preferably LWJGL 3